# Will Creative Cloud open CS2 files

Tags: cs2

I use CS2 on an old iMac (OS 10.6.8). If I upgrade to the latest iMac (Yosemite) and rent Creative Cloud will I be able to read my CS2 files.
If there's anyone out there who can help, I'd be most Grateful.
Norman

Comment: In general yes. Most new applications will open all previous version files. The issue is going *backwards* not forwards.

Comment: What Scott said. Also,if you can install the new cloud in Trial version on your older system, you can always try if you're really worried. But there's absolutely no reason why the CS2 wouldn't work. You can go back as far as opening 20 years old files without any issues!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to open your old files with creative cloud. Most software doesn't lose the ability to open old files, so you should be fine.